# datagridview Button Column in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-c#-express-2010

i am having a problem, whenever my row height is increased, the buttons height also increases, creating this:

[image]

How do i make the width of this button to 20?
Also, can an image column also contain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate this by altering the cell's Padding when the row changes height.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Form1 : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        ClientSize = new Size(640, 480);
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 36),
                AutoGenerateColumns = false,
                AllowUserToAddRows = false,
                RowHeadersVisible = false,
                ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize,
                Columns =
                {
                    new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "TextBox", DataPropertyName = "Text", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill, },
                    new DataGridViewButtonColumn { Name = "ButtonColumn", HeaderText = "Button", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader, DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Padding = new Padding(2) } },
                },
                DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new { Text = "Item " + i.ToString() }).ToList(),
            };

        dgv.RowHeightChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell = e.Row.Cells["ButtonColumn"];
                int pad = (e.Row.Height - 25) / 2;
                cell.Style.Padding = new Padding(2, pad, 2, pad);
            };

        Controls.Add(dgv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that for the button the   `button1.AutoSize = true;` is set to false

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.autosizemode

Comment: @Elite Gamer it should be in designer or when you click on the button in properties it might also be just AutoSize

Comment: i get all cells, fill, and all that, but not true or false

Comment: @Elite Gamer it got nothing to do with cells it just if you know your button name like button1 you can set auto-size to false

Comment: this is a button cell column in the datagridview